# Optimization Level panel is missing in Swift Compiler - Code Generation

Tags: swift, xcode7, build-settings

A project of mine totally misses the possibility of adjusting the optimization level for the Swift code and thereafter defaults to optimization for all options.
This is how the relative panel looks:
[image: Swift code generation panel]

How do I restore the possibility of adjusting the optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by setting the optimization in the project pane instead of the targets one, and now it appears also in this latter.